# How to run ffmpeg in a loop in the terminal to generate videos using files from every subdirectory

Tags: bash, for-loop, unix, terminal, command

I have some directory `./vis` that contains images that I want to loop through to generate a video. If I were to do it within one of the subdirectories, say `./vis/subdir1` I could run:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '*.jpg' out.mp4
```

Now I want to generate videos for every single subdirectory, I tried this:

```
for d in */; do ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i '${d}*.jpg' "${d}".mp4"; done
```

But it does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- '${d}*.jpg' is wrapped with single quotes and the variable `d` is not interpolated.
- "${d}".mp4" is not properly quoted. Besides, the variable `d` contains a trailing slash, which must be removed.

Then please try the following:

```
for d in */; do
    ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i "$d*.jpg" "${d%/}.mp4"
done
```